# How to make C# classes protobuf-net-serializable without referencing protobuf-net?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

First of all, I really like protobuf-net for it's speed and it's ease of use.
Now I'm developing a .NET class library and want to make some of my classes protobuf-net-ready without actually referencing it, because:

1. I don't know which environment my clients will use, so I don't know which protobuf-net binary to choose
2. I want to minimize the footprint size (maybe they won't need serialization at all)

As I understand, this can be done by writing .proto files manually. Could anyone explain me or give a link how to do this? Is there a way to generate .proto files from attribute description? And how will the client serialization/deserialization code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand, this can be done by writing .proto files manually

Nope; this is not necessary, and won't help.

Let's suppose you have a type currently like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Bar {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

There are two options to do what you want:

1. use the inbuilt platform attributes, for example:

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class Foo {
       [DataMember(Order=1)]
       public int Bar {get;set;}
       // ...
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   [XmlType]
   public class Foo {
       [XmlElement(Order=1)]
       public int Bar {get;set;}
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. configure the model explicitly at runtime (before the model tries to work with `Foo`):

   ```
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Foo), false).Add(1, "Bar");
   ```

   (the latter of course still requires you to talk to `ProtoBuf` at some point, but it does not require your POCO types to know about serialization)

Either of these should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But now I have another problem: my types look like lists unfortunately :( So I need "IgnoreListHandling = true", and seems like I can't do it with DataContract attribute.